# Save this question from agony - Sauvez cette question de l'agonie

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[Comment dériver les termes manquants ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/comment-deriver-les-termes-manquants)

The title is general but the only sub-question it contains and to which it's possible to respond (lost in the middle of loads of useless lines) is completely anecdotal to the problems raised.  For this reason, no-one has gone to the trouble of writing an answer.  The answer that's already there only tries to explain that there is no response in the general case.

I'm not the only one to have voted for closure - the two votes were reviewed and processed without follow-up by two different moderators.  I still think that it doesn't make for a good example and that it will remain sterile.

I don't understand its intention, and I don't see how to improve it.  I propose:

- Explaining how you understood it, and improving it if you know how to reformulate it in a clear and concise fashion.
- Convincing me that this question, in its current state, is well-formulated.
- Or voting for its closure (not a real question):

  > It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

  With the exception of "incomplete", I think the other 5 reasons apply.

---

[Comment dériver les termes manquants ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/4432/comment-deriver-les-termes-manquants)

Le titre est général mais la seule sous-question qu'elle contient et à laquelle il est possible de répondre (perdue au beau milieu d'une multitude de liens inutiles) est complètement anecdotique face à la problématique soulevée. Pour cette raison, personne ne se donne la peine de formuler une réponse. La réponse qui est déjà là essaye seulement d'expliquer qu'il n'y a pas de réponse au cas général.

Je ne suis pas le seul à avoir voté pour la clore, les deux votes ont été reviewés et classés sans suite par deux modérateurs différents. Je persiste à penser qu'elle ne fait pas bon exemple et qu'elle restera stérile.

Je ne comprends pas son but, et je ne vois pas comment l'améliorer. Je vous propose :

- d'expliquer comment vous l'avez comprise, et de l'améliorer si vous savez la reformuler de façon concise et claire.
- de me convaincre que cette question est, en l'état, bien formulée.
- ou de voter pour la clore (not a real question) :

  > It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ.

  À l'exception d'*incomplete*, je pense que les cinq autres motifs de clôture peuvent être retenus.

Comment: @Nikana: ça ne se voulait pas être une agression, est-ce que le nouveau titre convient mieux ?

Comment: À merveille ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I think that this question is understandable (if quite badly written), but too general.  It asks how to form a noun from another word.  However, there are many ways to do that, which depend both on the nature of the noun (concept, state, change, who's the agent, who's concerned, etc.), and on accidents of etymology.  Right now, I see two reasonable actions:

- Respond "there is no general rule; it's necessary to do things on a case-by-case basis".  This isn't very satisfying.
- Close as "not a real question", because the question is "overly broad": a whole chapter of a language treatise would be needed to respond to it.

---

Je pense que cette question est compréhensible (mais assez mal formulée), mais trop générale. Elle demande comment former un nom à partir d'un autre mot. Or il y a beaucoup de manières pour cela, qui dépendent à la fois de la nature du nom (concept, état, changement, personne qui agit, personne concernée, ...) et des hasards de l'étymologie. Du coup, je vois deux actions raisonnables :

- Répondre « il n'y a pas de règle générale, il faut voir au cas par cas ». Ce n'est pas très satisfaisant.
- Fermer comme « not a real question », parce que la question est « overly broad » : il faudrait tout un chapitre d'un traité de langue pour y répondre.

Comment: J'imagine que j'aurai une réponse à poster moi-même un jour, aussi bien ici que là-bas, mais en attendant, je serais aux anges si quelqu'un voulait bien me répondre le sommaire du dit chapitre de traité de langue, ou bien des pistes pour l'amorcer, ou bien faire la part des cas à distinguer. Je reconnais volontiers que la question est très floue, mais on comprendra que si j'avais su la préciser, je ne l'aurais pas posée (ainsi, du moins).

Comment: Une troisième action raisonnable : dresser une typologie et étudier les mécanismes récurrents dans la formation des mots nouveaux ?

Comment: Hehe the “overly broad” close reason is now available :-)

Answer (score 3):

J'y vois une question qui est à mi-chemin entre la langue française en particulier et la linguistique en général. Elle n'appelle effectivement aucune réponse concrète et définitive, c'est plutôt un thème de recherche, et c'est probablement l'aspect qui a rebuté Stéphane et d'autres, pour des raisons auxquelles je n'adhère pas, mais que je me refuse de juger, et que je comprends néanmoins.

Cette question donne à penser et correspond bien au thème de SE FL&U, donc je n'ai pas voté pour sa fermeture. Je ne crois pas qu'elle cause du tort à quelque visiteur que ce soit.

Ne laissons pas l'utilitarisme étouffer la poésie et la philologie...

Comment: Mille fois d'accord, le français ne s'apprend pas dans la grammaire, mais à l'oreille, et la mémoire affective fait son tri. Pas plus qu'on vous dit comment respirer aux premières secondes de votre arrivée dans l'air, on ne vous dit pas que maman est un nom féminin, *ahah* une interjection joyeuse en réponse aux guilis-guilis de la famille ébahie ... Déjà en mai 68 il était interdit d'interdire... mais ce mai-là était en France, pas dans un pays anglophone :)